# How do we set up kiosk mode in samsung tablet?

Tags: android, web, tablet, kiosk

I have samsung tablet tab 8, with android 9 installed.

I have trouble to make this tablet as kiosk app, I want to use it for opening my web page,

so everytime the tablet starts it directly open my web page only ( with wifi settings enabled )

I searched around and found Samsung KNOX, but I think it is a paid service, and I have trouble where to download it.

Is there another solution availible?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it as home app.

add this line inside intent-filter tag of your main activity in the manifest.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

Once is launched OS will ask you to set it as home forever or just once.

Comment: so I need to create new app,with that category tag in the app and open chrome directing to my website?

Comment: You can create an app with a webview redirected to your website. https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview